# How does the following line of JavaScript work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I came across the following code:

Javascript:

```
var ElementClicked = document.getElementById(IdClicked);
ElementClicked.className = ElementClicked.className == 'hidden' ? '' : 'hidden';
```

CSS:

```
div.hidden{
height: 500px;
}

div{
height: 0px;
-webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
transition: height 0.5s;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

The HTML contains two divs:

```
<div id="homepage" class='hidden'>
.
.
.
<div id="intro_page" >
```

The author calls the JavaScript function with the first div.

I am unable to understand clearly what the JavaScript function is doing. I know what a conditional operator is and how it works.

Can someone explain briefly what the function basically does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It toggles the hidden class. If the className was `'hidden'`, it is now `''`. If it was anything else, it is now `'hidden'`.

Comment: No, that won't work. Writing the original in full would be `if(E.cN == 'h') { E.cN = '';} else {E.cN = 'h';}`. Your suggestion would be  `if('h') {E.cN = '';} else {E.cN = 'h';}` which would just be `E.cN = '';`.

Comment: @Matt Because `'hidden'` always evaluates as `true`. You want to check the _equality_ `ElementClicked.className == 'hidden'`, i.e. whether the class name is _equal_ to `'hidden'`.

Answer (score 1):

The class of variable `ElementClicked` is being toggled between `'hidden'` and `''` using a ternary operator `?`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ElementClicked = document.getElementById(IdClicked);
```

ElementClicked *points/refers* to the **div** with id=**IdClicked**.

```
ElementClicked.className = ElementClicked.className == 'hidden' ? '' : 'hidden';
```

If ElementClicked *owns* the class "hidden", nothing appends. Else code adds class 'hidden' to ElementClicked.

**Brief, this code add class `hidden` to ElementClicked. The element with id=IdClicked gets class `hidden` when the JS code is executed.**

Comment: Actually, nothing gets ever appended here. What you mean is “replaced” (if `'hidden'` is present, the class name is replaced by the empty string, i.e. removed). Another thing that can be misinterpreted is `id=IdClicked`. `IdClicked` is not a string, but a variable that can hold any string.

Comment: That's right. Used to JQuery. It replaces or drop the classname.

Answer (score 0):

If i explain it line by line than,

```
ElementClicked.className = ElementClicked.className == 'hidden' ? '' : 'hidden';
```

this conditional operator checks if is is hidden, n if it is changes its state to ''.

Now,

```
div.hidden{
height: 500px;
}

div{
height: 0px;
-webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
transition: height 0.5s;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

is a css code for beautification and setting it as hidden

and the last one is html code where division is having homepage

```
<div id="homepage" class='hidden'>
.
.
.
<div id="intro_page" >
```